# Multiple linear regression between grids: reviewing the assumptions

Tags: r, linear-regression, geospatial, raster

I try to perform a regression analysis with 3 raster stacks in R, which also worked so far. Now I want to check the conditions of the model and I'm not sure how exactly that should work in this case. Since the model is calculated individually for each pixel, I cannot extract the residues for the entire investigation area and then check them. Therefore I currently have to extract the data of the variables for a few points / coordinates on a trial basis and then create an lm on which I then apply the tests (shapiro-test, breusch-pagan-test and VIF-test). does anyone know a more elegant solution?

```
NAO_stack <- stack("NAO_stack_fertig.tif")
AOD_stack <- stack("AOD_stack_fertig.tif")
CFC_stack <- stack("CFC_stack_fertig.tif")
NAO_AOD_stack <- stack(NAO_stack, AOD_stack)
NAO_CFC_stack <- stack(NAO_stack, CFC_stack)

NAO_AOD_CFC <- stack(NAO_stack, AOD_stack, CFC_stack)
NAO_CFC_AOD <- stack(NAO_stack, CFC_stack, AOD_stack)


fun1=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[56:110] ~ x[1:55] + x[111:165]);summary(m)$coefficients[,1] }}
Steigung_CFC <- calc(NAO_CFC_AOD, fun1)
names(Steigung_CFC) <- c("Intercept", "NAO_Steigung", "AOD_Steigung")
plot(Steigung_CFC[[3]])

fun2=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[56:110] ~ x[1:55] + x[111:165]);summary(m)$coefficients[,4] }}
p_value_CFC <- calc(NAO_CFC_AOD, fun2)
names(p_value_CFC) <- c("Intercept", "NAO_P_Value", "AOD_P_Value")
plot(p_value_CFC[[3]])

### pixel-by-pixel multiple linear regression with NAO and AOD / CFC as dependent variables

fun3=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[56:110] ~ x[1:55] + x[111:165]);summary(m)$adj.r.squared }}
r_squared_CFC <- calc(NAO_CFC_AOD, fun3)
plot(r_squared_CFC, main = "R²_CFC_multiple")

r_squared_AOD <- calc(NAO_AOD_CFC, fun3)
plot(r_squared_AOD, main = "R²_AOD_multiple")

### pixel-wise regression only with NAO as a dependent variable

fun4=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[56:110] ~ x[1:55]);summary(m)$adj.r.squared }}
r_squared_CFC_NAO <- calc(NAO_CFC_stack, fun4)
plot(r_squared_CFC_NAO, main = "R²_CFC")

r_squared_AOD_NAO <- calc(NAO_AOD_stack, fun4)
plot(r_squared_AOD_NAO, main = "R²_AOD")

r_squared_AOD_CFC <- calc(stack(CFC_stack, AOD_stack), fun4)
plot(r_squared_AOD_CFC, main = "R²_AOD_CFC")



### Extract data for a point to check the assumptions on the resulting LM model
XCoordinate = 8
YCoordinate = 61
points(XCoordinate, YCoordinate, pch = 15, cex = 0.5)
xy <- cbind(XCoordinate,YCoordinate)
xy
sp <- SpatialPoints(xy)
sp
data_CFC <- extract(CFC_stack, sp)  
data_CFC
data_CFC <- as.vector(data_CFC)
data_AOD <- extract(AOD_stack, sp) 
data_AOD
data_AOD <- as.vector(data_AOD)
data_NAO <- extract(NAO_stack, sp)
data_NAO
data_NAO <- as.vector(data_NAO)

CFC_lm <- lm(data_CFC ~ data_AOD + data_NAO)
summary(CFC_lm)
CFC_resid <- CFC_lm$residuals

AOD_lm <- lm(data_AOD ~ data_CFC + data_NAO)
summary(AOD_lm)
AOD_resid <- AOD_lm$residuals

shapiro.test(AOD_resid)
bptest(AOD_lm)
vif(AOD_lm)
```